# Mapped type is not an array type

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-generics, mapped-types

*I apologise for the rather undescriptive title, I'm not sure how I should properly title this question.*

(Hopefully this isn't one of those XY problems...)

I encountered this error whilst trying to write a generic `zipN` function in TypeScript.

```js
type Keys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: K };
type Longest2<T extends unknown[], U extends unknown[]> = Keys<T> extends [...Keys<U>, ...infer _] ? T : U;
type LongestN<T extends unknown[][]> = T extends [infer T0 extends unknown[], ...infer Ts extends unknown[][]] ? Longest2<T0, LongestN<Ts>> : T[0];
type OnlyNumeric<T> = T extends `${number}` ? T : never;
type MaybeIndex<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
type ZipN<T extends unknown[][]> = { [K in OnlyNumeric<keyof LongestN<T>>]: { [L in keyof T]: MaybeIndex<T[L], K> } };

export const zipN = <T extends unknown[][]>(...[head, ...tail]: T): ZipN<T> => [head, ...zipN(...tail) as ZipN<typeof tail>] as any;
```

[+ Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcA8AVAfFAvFA3lA2jFAJYB2UA1vAPYBmUKAugFyxQC+A3AFCiRQAZaqQDmEBMABMqKBAAewCKQAmCKAFdSFUtQDupfIwA0UAKqyFS1Rq079hjNjiJUGeYpVr8AOl-Pkpmgmvt5ktBAATlAA+oxQAPwMUKymPHzQQqLiwAByMu5WapraegaMDlhJBZ4EYZEMAAwWHtbFdmXBvnVRKGrVrbalhoZxiZliEtIoDSbj2Xm9aBisKPgNjGng0ADypAA2IDnqALaRxADGrpUozYVQAAYAJDikJwBGkez3CUmspBAAN0im34AFkAIYgD4ASRU8lQJhgjjY-TUVBAdCSiVWMDif0BwN4WygAC1iGAFrcam0huVGMi8IQSORdgcjqcIhckOjMXMJAslixcAQBMzKDR6ExWBCoRBYcp4asBMZYBh2BweNx5GBqBFgFBzsIJFAAF7knKVfKWamDex0tAAChC+AAFhBwcpOt5gODiHshSgAJSsMkUq6YDCu92eqAhM0Up2+H1+wNQcFqUN5dKY5N7NBxdNp0ggHhAA)

In the last line, TypeScript complains that `Type 'ZipN<unknown[][]>' is not an array type.`.

Note the `OnlyNumeric` type definition. I applied it to `keyof LongestN<T>` in order to get rid of all of the prototype methods and things like that because those are otherwise added to the object that `ZipN` produces.

I specifically said object in the previous sentence, because instead of a proper array type it produces an object with numeric keys. This is obviously what is causing the error I mentioned before, however I am really quite confused about why this is happening, especially since `{ [L in keyof T]: MaybeIndex<T[L], K> }` *does* yield an array (or tuple) type.

Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: Looks like you hit the bug at [ms/TS#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995). Mapped tuples only become tuples when iterating over the keys of a generic type parameter directly.  You can refactor slightly to introduce such a type parameter, as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/mby0PN), and that gives you the mapped tuple you presumably expected (although I don't know if the output is what you want, but that's not in scope here, right?  We're just trying to fix the tuple-to-object problem). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up a full answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yep, that solves it. As for the working part, just realised I had apparently made a few typos while retyping my code for this question so that's fixed now. [Working playground link here](https://shorturl.at/pvxTX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into the TypeScript bug/limitation described at [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995). The support for [mapping array/tuple types to other array/tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) only works when the array/tuple type whose properties you're iterating over is a bare [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  Since `LongestN<T>` is not such a generic type parameter, the mapped type maps over all the properties, including the array methods, and produces a non-array object.

It's quite a longstanding issue and it's not clear when or if it will ever be addressed.  Luckily you can work around it by refactoring to iterate over the keys of a generic type parameter `LNT` instead of `LongestN<T>`.  There are various ways to do that.  Here's one:

```
type ZipN<T extends unknown[][]> = LongestN<T> extends infer LNT ?
    { [K in keyof LNT]: { [L in keyof T]: MaybeIndex<T[L], K> } } : never;
```

This uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to "copy" `LongestN<T>` into a new type parameter `LNT`.

You can verify that this produces actual array/tuples now:

```
type Z = ZipN<[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]>;
// type Z = [[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
```

And your error about `ZipN<T>` not being an array goes away:

```
const zipN = <T extends unknown[][]>(...[head, ...tail]: T): ZipN<T> =>
    [head, ...zipN(...tail) as ZipN<typeof tail>] as any; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcA8AVAfFAvFA3lA2jFAJYB2UA1vAPYBmUKAugFyxQC+A3AFCiRQAZaqQDmEBMABMqKBAAewCKQAmCKAFdSFUtQDupfIwA0UAKqyFS1Rq079hjNjiJUGeYpVr8AOl-Pkpmgmvt5ktBAATlAA+oxQAPwMUKymPHzQQqLiwAByMu5WapraegaMDlhJBZ4EYZEMAAwWHtbFdmXBvnVRKGrVrbalhoZxiZliEtIoDSbj2Xm9aBisKPgNjGng0ACyAIYgAEYQAJIq8qgmMI5s-WpUIHRJiaswcaykEABukZv8AFrEMALZqFGwlezlRjXOYSBZuSw1bqCHIoBLcKAY3AEIhkSg0egCFEsLH4AQkcj3R5MVh7Q4nM5yVCk4ywDDsDjJKAfb4RHi8LZQP6VAFApD4NYmACMJkkLPwAGYTAAWEwAVkYUJ4AHotVB0oLKuKZlB5XLpVAlXLJGqNdxuPIwNQIsAoABjYQSKAAL0BOUq+QRA3BZQcAAoQvgABYQXbKTreYC7YgAG2JKAAlKwRXCsGh0ZiozG41AQj6geHfImU+moLs1NmkOlHlXk2g4nXa6QQDwgA)